# Python, adding methods to a class, Error: global name is not defined

Tags: python, class, methods

I am trying to understand why my method, `increment4`, is not working. All of these methods worked fine as functions, but now that I have converted them into methods something is not working. I have replaced the "Time" object names with "self". I experimented with keeping and deleting "return".
**EDIT** I was not using dot notation, as was kindly pointed out to me. I made a few changes. Now Python is giving me a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users//Desktop/temp.py", line 33, in <module>
    currenttime.increment4(4000)
  File "/Users//Desktop/temp.py", line 22, in increment4
    newtime = float(total_seconds).make_time()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'make_time'
>>>
```

Line 33 is:

```
currenttime.increment4(4000)
```

Line 22 is:

```
newtime = float(total_seconds).make_time()
```

And here is the whole thing:

```
class Time:
    def printTime(self):
        print str(time.hours)+":"+str(time.minutes)+":"+str(time.seconds)

    def make_time (self):
        time = Time ()
        time.hours = self / 3600
        time.minutes = (self % 3600) / 60
        time.seconds = (self % 3600) % 60
        return time

    def covertTOseconds (self):
        hours = self.hours * 3600
        minutes = self.minutes * 60
        seconds = self.seconds
        amt_in_seconds = hours + minutes + seconds
        return amt_in_seconds

    def increment4 (self, increaseINseconds):
        total_seconds = self.covertTOseconds() + increaseINseconds
        newtime = float(total_seconds).make_time()
        newtime.printTime()


currenttime = Time()
currenttime.hours = 3
currenttime.minutes = 47
currenttime.seconds = 45



currenttime.increment4(4000)
```

Comment: `self.covertTOseconds()`, and fix your naming conventions per PEP-8 (`convert_to_seconds`).

Comment: Thank you Jon! I implemented your suggestions and I am editing my question. It's throwing a different error now.

Comment: And the error message tells you precisely what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your code a little bit:

```
class Time:
    def printTime(self, time):
        print str(time.hours)+":"+str(time.minutes)+":"+str(time.seconds)

    def increment4(self, increaseINseconds):
        seconds = self.covertTOseconds() + increaseINseconds
        time = self.makeTime (seconds)
        print time

    def makeTime(self, totalseconds):
        time = Time ()
        time.hours = totalseconds / 3600
        time.minutes = (totalseconds % 3600) / 60
        time.seconds = (totalseconds % 3600) % 60
        return time

    def covertTOseconds(self):
        hours = self.hours * 3600
        minutes = self.minutes * 60
        seconds = self.seconds
        totalseconds = hours + minutes + seconds
        return totalseconds
```

As the error shows `converTOseconds` is not defined because it should be called with `self`, also it takes no arguments. Thus, you need to change from `covertTOseconds (self)` to `self.convertTOseconds()`. Hope this helps.

Since you have updated the question, it seems to me that what you might want to do is have a class like this:

```
class Time:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hours = None
        self.minutes = None
        self.seconds = None
        self.total_seconds = None

    def to_seconds(self):
        hours = self.hours * 3600
        return (self.hours * 3600) + (self.minutes * 60) + self.seconds

    def increment(self, x):
        self.total_seconds = self.to_seconds() + x
        self.hours = self.total_seconds / 3600
        self.minutes = (self.total_seconds % 3600) / 60
        self.seconds = (self.total_seconds % 3600) % 60
        self.__str__()

    def __str__(self):
        print("{0}:{1}:{2}".format(self.hours, self.minutes, self.seconds))
```

Then you can use that class as follows:

```
c_time = Time()
c_time.hours = 3
c_time.minutes = 47
c_time.seconds = 45

c_time.increment(4000)
```

This outputs:

```
4:54:25
```

Comment: Thank you Jose. I made a few edits based on your suggestions. I am getting a different error now: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'makeTime'. I can't figure out what is the missing concept here...

Comment: You have modified your method `increment4` which tries to call the method `makeTime` on `total_seconds` which is an integer type.

Comment: Sorry I wrote this before I saw your edits!  I will try them before I ask another question. Thanks!

Comment: This is perfect. You used some concepts that I haven't learned yet, so I will google them because this was clean and mean. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped :). This [tutorial](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex40.html) might help you understand classes in Python, it's very basic but I think it's a good starting point. Hope it helps.